# Creating pages and getting their values from the database table

Tags: posts, query-posts, query

I need to make inquries from my new website. I want to know whether Wordpress is capable of this:

Say it I have such a table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `base_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `page_type` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `page_title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `page_content` text NOT NULL,
  `previous_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `next_positive_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `next_negative_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;  


id..base_id..page_type..page_title..page_content..previous_id...next_positive_id..next_negative_id
1..1..question...."Character test"..."Do you like cats"....0....2....3
2..1..middle question.."Character test"...."Do you like dogs"....1....4....5
```

First question is "Do you like cats". This is "page content". Page title is "Character test". If user selects yes, he is redirected to page 4, if no then redirected to page 5.

Page titles, questions, next page's links etc. will be taken from the database table. I put a flow example below. Is it possible to make this in Wordpress ? 
I need to change only database entries and then the site content wil be updated automatically. 
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress does not have relationship support among the posts. So for you to do that you have create a new table to store the post id and the linked post id. You need to do custom query every time that table needs to be updated.